# Failover clustering with apache2 on linux(ubuntu) and file synchonization

Tags: 12.04, apache2, failover

I am interested in creating a failover cluster on Ubuntu(12.04.3 LTS) using apache2.

I am currently using ucarp.

Q1: I followed instructions on this [first link](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/simple-failover-cluster-using-ucarp-on-ubuntu/) but I have a problem in file synrchonization. This [second link](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/file-synchronization-between-two-ubuntu-servers-using-unison/) from the same website describes the procedure.

In the first link, the address 192.168.1.202 that is using is a virtual IP or do I put my own IP there?

- If I put my own IP (and subnet) I canot get it to work. I get

  > Failed to bring up eth0.
  >   during networking restart and in
  >   ifconfig
  >   I cannot get the "eth0:ucarp" virtual address, only the "eth0" and "lo"
- If i put 192.168.1.202 I think that I am wrong because that is not my real IP(is that right).

Can anyone help me out here?

Q2: Do you know another easy way to create a cluster with apache2 on ubuntu and virtualize the failover cluster mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at pacemaker. It is a standard de facto of building such HA solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am alreading searching into it, do you have a nice guide for a simple failover cluster application with apache(and pacemaker)?

Comment: Also, I am looking for a simple application, I am unsure whether pacemaker would be necessary. Regards.